# Why do I have to use aggregators when using MIN/MAX Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to get the `MIN` value from a column, and the corresponding `date`

```
SELECT date, MIN(speed) FROM foo 
    INNER JOIN bar
        ON foo.id = bar.foo_id;
```

That does not work

> Column date must be used in GROUP BY or in another aggregate function

I do not understand why I cannot select the date, where `MIN(speed)` is. Its in the same row, just another attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you can't do what you want is because that is not how SQL is defined.  I don't think your version would be very useful.  After all, what would your query do if you had `AVG(speed)`?  Or both `MIN(speed)` and `MAX(speed)`?

In any case, what you want to do is easy enough using `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT date, speed
FROM foo JOIN
     bar
     ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
ORDER BY speed
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

> *I do not understand why I cannot select the date, where MIN(speed) is*

An aggregate function reduces many rows to just one row. The result of `min(speed)` without a GROUP BY (as you used it) yields a **single** value (and row) - but you would have multiple values for the `date` column

The error message is telling you, that Postgres won't just pick a random value for you and you have to specify some rule to pick the date value or combination of date and speed you want.

Comment: I understand that now. I did not know that `MIN()` is an aggregator - and I think it does not make much sense (as far as I have knowledge). Because why would you aggregate when want a the minimum value? That could easily be done by just telling  "that is the row with the minimum value". But maybe that is because Postgres somehow works internaly in a way I do not understand and that is why its done like this.

Comment: @Stophface: well this is how an "aggregate" is defined in SQL - it reduces many rows to a single row e.g. `sum()` behaves in the same way.